# select date ranges for multiple years in r

Tags: r

I have a data set containing data for about 4.5 years. I'm trying to create two different data frames from this, for what I will call holiday and non-holiday periods. There are multiple periods per year, and these periods will repeat over multiple years.

For example, I'd like to choose a time period between Thanksgiving and New Year's Day, as well as periods prior to Valentine's Day and Mother's Day for each year, and make this my holiday data frame. Everything else would be non-holiday.

I apologize if this has been asked before, I just can't find it. I found a similar question for SQL, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this in R.

I've tried filtering and selecting, to no avail.

```
wine.holiday <- wine.sub2 %>% 
   select(total, cdate) %>% 
   subset(cdate>=2011-11-25, cdate<=2011-12-31)
wine.holiday

Source: local data frame [27,628 x 3]
Groups: clubgroup_id.x [112]

   clubgroup_id.x total      cdate
            (chr) (dbl)     (date)
1               1    45 2011-10-04
2               1    45 2011-10-08
3               1    45 2011-10-09
4               1    45 2011-10-09
5               1    45 2011-10-11
6               1    45 2011-10-15
7               1    45 2011-10-24
8               1    90 2011-11-13
9               1    45 2011-11-18
10              1    45 2011-11-26
..            ...   ...        ...
```

Clearly something isn't right, because not only is it not limiting the date range, but it's including a column in the data frame that I'm not even selecting.

Comment: Apparently `wine.sub2` is already grouped by `clubgroup_id.x`, which is why it's turning up. Also, the `dplyr` equivalent of `subset` is `filter`, which is much less likely to cause issues. You may also like the `chron::is.holiday` function, which is configurable to your own list of holidays.

Comment: Please show few lines of example data

Comment: @alistaire Thanks, I'll check out the chron package. I didn't know about that one.

Comment: @akrun The data above was the result of the code that didn't work. I think I have at least part of a solution now.

Comment: @alistaire FYI, I couldn't figure out how to do this with `chron`, but I was able to use the built in holidays in `dateTime`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, dplyr uses `filter` not `subset`. Just a simple change to the code you've got (therefore not a complete solution to your issue, but hopefully helps) should get the subset working.

```
wine.holiday <- wine.sub2 %>% 
   select(total, cdate)
wine.holiday <- subset(wine.holiday, cdate>=as.Date("2011-11-25") & cdate<=as.Date("2011-12-31"))
wine.holiday
```

Or, to stick with dplyr piping:

```
wine.holiday <- wine.sub2 %>% 
    select(total, cdate) %>%
    filter( cdate>=as.Date("2011-11-25") & cdate<=as.Date("2011-12-31") )
wine.holiday
```

EDIT to add: If the dplyr select isn't working (it looks fine to me), you could try this:

```
wine.holiday <- subset( wine.sub2, select = c( total, cdate ) )
wine.holiday <- subset(wine.holiday, cdate>=as.Date("2011-11-25") & cdate<=as.Date("2011-12-31"))
wine.holiday
```

You could, of course, combine those two lines into one. This makes it harder to read, but would probably improve the processing efficiency:

```
wine.holiday <- subset(wine.sub2, cdate>=as.Date("2011-11-25") & cdate<=as.Date("2011-12-31"), select=c(total,cdate) )
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense, but for some reason, it's not working.  I'm getting:      > wine.holiday <- wine.sub2 %>% 
    +   select(total, cdate)
    > wine.holiday <- filter(wine.holiday, cdate >= 2011-11-25 & cdate <=    2012-12-25)
    > head(wine.holiday)
    Source: local data frame [0 x 3]
    Groups: clubgroup_id.x [0]

    Variables not shown: clubgroup_id.x (chr), total (dbl), cdate (date)  Not sure why it's still looking for clubgroup_id.x when it isn't in the select function.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make sure the filter parameters pass as date class. That might help.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. It was already in date format, but the missing quotes was the problem. Although it's still putting in the clubgroup_id.x variable column even though I'm not selecting it for wine.holiday. Weird. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: You're welcome. That select line seems like it should work, but you could `subset` with a `select` parameter instead. I'll add a section to the answer you could try.

Comment: Is there any chance you could help me with some logic? Now that I have a data table containing start and end dates for my holiday period, I need to figure out how to separate out my sales data by sales within the holiday period and sales outside the holiday period. I think I need to merge that table into my data, just not sure that's the right approach. If so, can you point me at the best tool to use for this? I believe I've seen another SO post on this, so I'll have to study that again to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: There are a few ways you could achieve what you want, but it's best if you start a new question and we'll answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another method for this through looking through SO posts (took a while).

```
> library(dateTime)
> wine.holiday <- data.table(start = c(as.Date(USThanksgivingDay(2010:2020))), 
+                            end = as.Date(USNewYearsDay(2011:2021))-1)
> wine.holiday
         start        end
 1: 2010-11-25 2010-12-31
 2: 2011-11-24 2011-12-31
 3: 2012-11-22 2012-12-31
 4: 2013-11-28 2013-12-31
 5: 2014-11-27 2014-12-31
 6: 2015-11-26 2015-12-31
 7: 2016-11-24 2016-12-31
 8: 2017-11-23 2017-12-31
 9: 2018-11-22 2018-12-31
10: 2019-11-28 2019-12-31
11: 2020-11-26 2020-12-31
```

I still need to figure out how to add other ranges (e.g. two weeks before Valentine's Day or Mother's Day) to this, and will update this answer if/when I figure it out.